# kubernetes flannel network is not working

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

network cant connected between (pod and pod) or (pod and node).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZkUf.png)

flannel.1 interface have same mac address:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DszGu.png)

k8s version: v1.23.1
os version: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
flannel version: quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.14.0

Why are the same MAC addresses generated?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue which is actually effect of a race condition between systemd (>242) and flannel where systemd overrides the MAC address of the `flannel.1` network interface.

The issue was described here: https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel/issues/1155 and fixed via https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel/pull/1485.

Make sure to use the latest version of flannel (or v0.14.1 or v0.15.1).